Importing cryptography Issue
First, I was writing a program that allows people to create a secure file like writing a file and encrypt it I started for 3 weeks the cryptography was working just fine till today I wanted to run my program as always then I got the shock I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Programing\Projects\Projects_Python\Secure_space\Code\Code.py", line 1, in <module>
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'

Please if you can help with some information contact me please.
I tried to install it again and no result,
even chatgpt couldn't help,
I've never been in this position before.

I had a very similar problem when I built my first python module. The issue is that you probably didn't build the python module locally and are referencing it in another directory.
I recommend watching pixegami's video onn Pypi modules:
pixegami's video
This is the video that taught me how to build python modules and how to properly use them locally, globally, etc. You can skip to 2:06 but I recommend you watch from the beginning to make sure your project has a similar structure

I tried this way but it didn't work I have no idea what's going on . but thank you very much for your help
